# How to generate PMD reports in PDF format though VSTS Build?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

[image][image]I have sonar and necessary softwares installed in VSTS Private agent.As part of the build I am getting checkstyle and Findbugs reports in the Artifacts section of VSTS build.But though I have enabled the PMD option in VSTS Run code analysis option I don't see any PMD reports after the build success.Please help me out how to solve this issue.When I installed sonar governance plugin and sonar pdfreport plugin my sonarqube server is not launching the localhost.So let me know how to resolve this issue.I am using sonar 6.7.1 version.

Image 1[image: Image 2[![Image 3[![Image 4[![Image 5]][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O1OL.jpg)][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucD4p.jpg)][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eeRY.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the detail settings and steps of your build definition?

Comment: @Marina Liu - MSFT,Please find the screen shots above and help me out.I have attached 4 images.Please check.

Comment: Did you install the related plugins (checkstyle, PMD and FindBugs) in your sonarqube server? And What if you use maven task with version 2.0 (https://imgur.com/a/2VC7z), and what’s the build logs?

Comment: @Marina Liu - MSFT, What plugins are required  and how to install in sonar qube server?

Comment: If I install sonarpdfreport plugin or governance plugin then my sonarqube server is hunging.

Comment: I can see the PMD reports in the artifacts section of VSTS build in html and xml format but I want in PDF format in the artifacts section as well as in sonarqube server.How to generate in PDF format ? As I said I have tried to copy the above 2 plugins for PDF generation but my sonar server is getting hung.So please help here.

Comment: To view the PMD analysis report the PMD plugin (https://imgur.com/a/PU5vP) is enough. After install the PMD plugin, it will shows Install Pending, you should restart the server (https://imgur.com/a/JKBCa). Besides, can you show the screen shots that you saw it as html or xml format via build artifacts?

Comment: Which PMD plugin I need to install? Is there any default plugin installed as part of the SonarQube installation? Can I have the PMD plugin download link or let me know the name of the plugin I need to place inside SonarQube extension/plugins directory?

Comment: Beside to that I have attached the screen shot as you asked..Please help me out..

Comment: There is only one PMD plugin shows in marketplace. And it's not installed by default, you can search the plugin and install (SonarQube home page -> Administaration -> Marketplace Tab).

Comment: I can't find the PMD plugin from Market place.Please see the attached screen shot.

Comment: Please help me how to download this plugin?

Comment: The source of the PMD plugin is here https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-pmd. Not sure why you can't fins the PMD, but I'm using SonarQube 7.0.

Comment: The link which you shared has sonar pmd source but May I know how to  download the PMD plugin as a jar file.Please let me know.By the way I have installed SonarQube 7.0 but I don't see PMD plugin under market place.So please help me how to download the plugin.

Comment: Please try with this link http://www.sonarplugins.com/pmd.

Comment: Thanks Marina.Can you confirm where can I place this PMD Plugin in sonarQube server? Do I need to place in extensions folder of sonarQube or which folder I need to copy this plugin?And confirm whether we can get PDF reports using this plugin?

Comment: You can copy the plugin into the unzip folder like `c:\sonarqube-7.0\sonarqube-7.0\extensions\plugins\sonar-php-plugin-2.12.1.3018.jar` and check if sonarqube marketplace Tab show the PMD plugin as installed. And for the PMD plugin to show PDF reports, I'm not sure. You can confirm by creating a new question with `sonarqube` tag, so that it can be better answered.

Comment: When I install PMD plugin my build is failing with the report parameter missing error.What can I do now?

Comment: What's the detail error message?